# Where can I find a good .NET PDF library?

Tags: .net, pdf

We're webifying a winforms app with a mix of active reports and crystal reports. All will somehow be converted to PDF. There are so many tools out there. Anyone have experience with/recommendations for tools that we can use?

SQL Reports are one possibility, but I'd like to explore other options instead of just taking what initially seems to be the easy way.

Answer (score 6):

Have you taken a look at iTextSharp?

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've used this a couple of times in projects now. One big advantage is that you can use iTextSharp to add a password to an existing PDF file, which was an issue I had to resolve.

Comment: iTextSharp is good if you know how you want the page to look. It's fairly low-level in the sense that you must describe the exact placement of all rectangles, lines of text, etc. If you have a fairly static layout in mind it is quite reasonable to use. If you need something more high level with auto-flowing layout, it may not do what you need.

Comment: Despite the recommendations for itextsharp, it's based on 1.1 framework. We'll be moving to 3.5 on new boxes that have to be certified by DISA, and we're trying to move out of the 1.0/1.0 arena. Anyone know of a port of iTextSharp to the 3.0/3.5 platform?

Comment: You should have no problem using iTextSharp with the .NET 3.0/3.5 framework. You just need to make sure you have the 1.1 framework installed on the machine so the iTextSharp assembly can function properly.

Comment: There are licensing issues with iText : "While the AGPL license has no direct financial cost there are clear requirements for AGPL use. Buying a commercial license is mandatory as soon as you develop activities involving the iText software without disclosing the source code of your own applications."

Answer (score 3):

I have used http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm and it works really well for me. You can add images and everything. I am using it where I take XML and XSLT as a template, pass in the transform (the XSLT converts to HTML) and the PDF generator will generate my page properly.

Yes, the component has a cost, but I find it worth it some times to pay a small cost then spending hours and hours trying to get something else to work.

Answer (score 2):

DynamicPDF

http://www.cete.com/Products/GeneratorForNET/

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if this is what you are looking for, but Crystal reports can export the reports directly to PDF so you can generate the report on the server directly in PDF format and return that PDF to the user.

If what you are looking for is a tool that allows you to generate PDF files directly then a good option is, like some colleagues has commented, iTextSharp. With iTextSharp you can generate PDF documents programmatically from scratch or from XML files.

Some useful links:
[iTextSharp on Sourceforge](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)
[ITextSharp section on iT3XT.com](http://www.1t3xt.com/products/itextsharp.php)

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experiences with [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/PDFsharp/).  It's fairly low level and provides a familiar way to draw text, images, etc. on a document.  Here's some [sample code](http://www.pdfsharp.net/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=29).

It's free to use for both personal & commercial projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're looking for a component to create PDF files or trying to migrate your current reports formats to an ASP.NET site where the data can be downloaded as a PDF file.  For the former I'd recommend iTextSharp.  For the latter I'd recommend Devexpress XtraReports.  Note that XtraReports supports exporting to PDF format out of the box.

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/

Answer (score 0):

I have a little experience with iText for Java which seems to a well-accepted solution; there's a .NET version called [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

if all you need to is to convert a report to PDF the VisualStudio Report Generator will do that for you out of the box.  Otherwise I second iTextSharp.

Answer (score 0):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is good for pretty much anything. I use it for all my .NET projects.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [Expert PDF Converter](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/) which lets me create a PDF from the HTML. I basically render an aspx page and send the output to the component which turns it into a pdf. It's nice in that I can print a WYSIYG experience for the user. Its not perfect but for $500 its a good value.